# Wordpress - replace read more with specfic word

Tags: wordpress

I want to replace `( more ... )` with link: `<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">Read More →</a>`

I try this code :-

```
function replace_excerpt($content) {
    return str_replace('[...]',
           '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">Read More →</a>',
           $content
    );
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_excerpt');
```

But not work why !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [excerpt_more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) filter like below;

```
function custom_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read More → </a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'custom_more', 1000);
```

Put above code in **functions.php**

**Edit:** Maybe your theme also uses `the_excerpt`. So, you need to increase priority of your plugin with 3rd parameter in above code;

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'custom_more', 1000);
```

Comment: @user49575 see my updated asnwer. If you increase priority of your filter, you can make it work

Comment: I have tested it on my website, Have you put code in functions.php

Comment: Have you implemented it on anywhere else?

Comment: So you need to remove it. And use the one I gave you above in fuctions.php

Answer (score 0):

In your template file, replace `the_content();` with `the_content( __( 'Read More →' ) );`. No need to add the permalink or anything else.

Comment: Are you using the more tag in visual editor to trim your words or are you using the excerpt to show your text

Comment: Which theme are you using and are you using a child theme